# Key listener script with GUI won't work (Tkinter)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pynput

I need to "listen" if the user types the ENTER key while a GUI application runs in background (using Tkinter), if the user type the ENTER key a messagebox should show up, but as soon as I run the script the GUI do not appear, and if I press ENTER a huge list of errors appears in the console, and the GUI shows up (the messagebox won't). I think I'm missing something in the "listening" function:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
import logging
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

window = Tk() 
window.title("i'm listening...")
window.geometry("400x400")

def on_press(key):
    logging.info(str(key))
    if str(key) == "Key.enter":
        msg = messagebox.showinfo( "simple message", "you clicked the enter button!")
        '''
        do
        other
        stuffs
        '''

with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()

window.mainloop()
```

Console:

```
RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop
```

Thanks for your help/tips!

Comment: Why would it even *cross your mind* to use `pynput` with `Tkinter`?  `Tkinter` has perfectly usable keyboard event handling already, use `.bind()` here.  As for your error: `pynput`'s Listener necessarily runs in a separate thread, `Tkinter' doesn't work well with threads.

Comment: try changing: `with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()` to `listener = Listener(on_press=on_press)
listener.start()`

Comment: @eyllanesc That worked, many thanks sir!